# Is there a way to combine multiple graphs into one singular graph?

Tags: next.js, chart.js

I'm not sure how do I search for this because I really have no idea how to type it out so I apologize in advance if there is already an existing solution out there.

My problem:
Let's say I have several sections, and each section has a sub-section. For instance, for Section A has 3 sub-sections, Section A (1), Section A (2), and Section A (3). Currently, I am able to produce 3 **different** graphs for each sub-section of section A. Now, is it possible using ChartJS, to combine all of them into a singular graph so there will just be 1 big graph consisting of all these sub-sections like such:
[Single Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfNv5.png)

Note: Currently talking about only vertical line graphs.

Thanks.

I'm only able to create a graph for each section, not sure how to combine each section into 1 graph.

This is currently how the feedbackData looks like,

```json
[
  {
    "fbID": "f6498d26-ad0c-4abd-bf77-e194489643c6",
    "fbSectionA1": 4,
    "fbSectionA2": 4,
    "fbSectionA3": 3,
    "fbSectionA4": 4,
    "fbSectionA5": 4,
    "fbSectionB1": 4,
    "fbSectionB2": 4,
    "fbSectionB3": 4,
    "fbSectionB4": 3,
    "fbSectionC1": 3,
    "fbSectionD1": 4,
    "fbSectionEAdditional": "Data 1",
    "fbSectionEChanges": "Data 1",
    "fbSectionESuggestions": "Data 1"
  },
  {
    "fbID": "df23aec1-b8eb-47bb-95b5-b85t87c5d135",
    "fbSectionA1": 4,
    "fbSectionA2": 4,
    "fbSectionA3": 4,
    "fbSectionA4": 4,
    "fbSectionA5": 4,
    "fbSectionB1": 4,
    "fbSectionB2": 4,
    "fbSectionB3": 4,
    "fbSectionB4": 4,
    "fbSectionC1": 4,
    "fbSectionD1": 4,
    "fbSectionEAdditional": "-",
    "fbSectionEChanges": "-",
    "fbSectionESuggestions": "-"
  },
  {
    "fbID": "f72c7e26-7bb1-47f7-823d-75c375108c5f",
    "fbSectionA1": 5,
    "fbSectionA2": 4,
    "fbSectionA3": 4,
    "fbSectionA4": 5,
    "fbSectionA5": 5,
    "fbSectionB1": 5,
    "fbSectionB2": 5,
    "fbSectionB3": 5,
    "fbSectionB4": 4,
    "fbSectionC1": 4,
    "fbSectionD1": 5,
    "fbSectionEAdditional": "None",
    "fbSectionEChanges": "None",
    "fbSectionESuggestions": "Data 3"
  }
]
```

You can see that each row has data for all sections, so I need to extract the sections. Currently, this is how I loop the sections and each section has their own graph,

```
<div className="w-full mb-5">
    {sectionsToDisplay.map((sectionName) => (
        <IndividualFeedback
        key={sectionName}
        sectionName={sectionName}
        feedbackData={feedbackData}
        />
    ))}
</div>
```

and this is what I did with the feedbackData in the feedbackGraph component,

```
const prepareChartData = () => {
        const labels: string[] = ['Strongly Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Agree', 'Strongly Agree'];
        const data: number[] = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            const columnName = `${sectionName}` as keyof FeedbackDataType;
            const ratingCounts = calculateRatingCounts(columnName);
            const ratingData = Object.keys(ratingCounts).map((rating) => ratingCounts[rating]);
            data.push(...ratingData);
            console.log(columnName);
        }

        console.log(data);

        return {
            labels,
            data,
        };
    };
```

```
const calculateRatingCounts = (columnName: keyof FeedbackDataType) => {
        const ratingCounts: { [rating: string]: number } = {};

        for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            ratingCounts[i.toString()] = 0;
        }

        feedbackData.forEach((feedback) => {
            const rating = parseInt(feedback[columnName], 10);
            if (!isNaN(rating) && rating >= 1 && rating <= 5) {
                ratingCounts[rating.toString()] += 1;
            }
        });

        return ratingCounts;
    };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

> *Let's say I have several sections, and each section has a sub-section. For instance, for Section A has 3 sub-sections, Section A (1), Section A (2), and Section A (3). Currently, I am able to produce 3 different graphs for each sub-section of section A.*

**Solution :**

> Pass multiple data items (Objects) under dataset array,

**Im not sure If you mean `ChartJS` [5](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) or `react-chartjs-2` [4](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/vertical-bar-chart) but still solution would be the same.**

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
      labels:['Sec:A-1','Sec:A-2','Sec:A-3'] , // x-axis labels
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Label A-1',           // Legend label
          data: [10,40,70],

        },
        {
          label: 'Label A-2',           // Legend label
          data: [20,50,80],

        },
        {
          label: 'Label A-3',           // Legend label
          data: [30,60,90],

        }
      ]
    },
   });

 

</script>
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

**The below code is from Official ChartJS documentation :**

**Bar Chart Border Radius Example** [1](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html):

You can see that, `datasets` key is an array of Objects of each section,

So you should pass your section A-1, A-2, A-3 as objects in `datasets` array. *(Utils is provided by ChartJS).*
`Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG)` is an array of random numbers.

Ignore the appearance its because of styling(`borderColor, backgroundColor, borderWidth, borderRadius`).

```
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Fully Rounded',          // here will be your section name A-1
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG), // here will be your data values [1,2...]
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.red, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      borderSkipped: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Small Radius',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderSkipped: false,
    }
  ]
};
```

*Similarly in Stacked Bar Chart Example [2](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html) look at the dataset.*

**So in your case,** *(I have excluded extra code related to styling)*:

```
datasets: [
        {
          label: 'A-1',          
          data: [10,20,30],
        },
       {
          label: 'A-2',          
          data: [50,60,70],
        },
        {
          label: 'A-3',          
          data: [90,100,10],
        },
      ]
```

Please Read More:

1. **Bar Chart Border Radius :**  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html
2. **Stacked Bar Chart** :  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html
3. **Utils**: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/utils.html
4. **react-chartjs-2 :** https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/vertical-bar-chart
5. **Chart.js :** https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment. If this answer was helpful, then you may mark it as answer.***

Comment: Hello,

Yes, that is what I am looking for! However, let's say I have components (NextJS 13) called FeedbackTable and FeedbackGraph. I have 4 sections, Section A 1-5, Section B 1-4, Section C 1 and Section D 1 so each row of data (called FeedbackData) has these columns. I pass this FeedbackData from FeedbackTable to FeedbackGraph. How do I extract the FeedbackData based on the sections, and then create a singular graph for those sections in FeedbackGraph? Currently, I have one graph for each section meaning I called the FeedbackGraph based on all the sections I have (5+4+1+1=11). Thanks.

Comment: Also, this is the current Chart.js I'm using, "chart.js": "^4.4.0". I'm cracking my head to figure out how to do this but to no avail D:

Comment: *If you can give a dummy data (an example of data that you give to FeedbackTable) & how does the current table looks,  then I might give a last try.*

Comment: Hello, I have updated the post to include my codes and a part of how the feedbackData looks like. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. Just took some time to manually separate the data,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).